# SQL - split data into two columns based on identifier

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains the product categories/headers and product names but all in one column. I need to split it out into separate `Category` and `Product` columns. I also have a helper column `Header_Flag` which can be used to determine if the row contains the `header` or `product name`. The input table looks like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Product        |     Header_Flag  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Furniture      |         Y        |
|      Bed            |         N        |
|      Table          |         N        |
|      Chair          |         N        |
|      Cosmetics      |         Y        |
|      Lip balm       |         N        |
|      Lip stick      |         N        |
|      Eye liner      |         N        |
|      Apparel        |         Y        |
|      Shirt          |         N        |
|      Trouser        |         N        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

The output format I'm looking for would be like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Category       |     Product      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Furniture      |       Bed        |
|      Furniture      |       Table      |
|      Furniture      |       Chair      |
|      Cosmetics      |       Lip balm   |
|      Cosmetics      |       Lip stick  |
|      Cosmetics      |       Eye liner  |
|      Apparel        |       Shirt      |
|      Apparel        |       Trouser    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: I can't see how you get from your sample data to your expected results. What denotes the order of your data in your table?

Comment: The products are listed under the category they belong to. So unless you encounter the next `Y` in the `Header_Flag` column you'd assume that the product belongs to the category just above. Hope I've understood and answered your question correctly.

Comment: This is another one that needs the big assumption, i.e. that there's some way to reproduce the original sequence

Comment: So, what `ORDER BY` clause would you use to get the data in the same order, @Chipmunk_da ? I only see 2 columns, and neither of those would retain said order.

Comment: @Larnu would having an auto-increment `Identity` column in the sample data help?

Comment: It would, @Chipmunk_da .

Comment: Great, I'll include that in. So can we just assume that it exists?

Comment: An Identity column would only help if it was strictly increasing and assigned in the sort order you're looking for.  Imo it's better not to confound Id columns with sequences.

Comment: Eye Liner --> Shirt? Is that correct required output? or Apparel --> Shirt and Apparel --> Trouser?

Comment: @DawoodAwan Sorry that's a typo on my end and Apparel --> Shirt and Apparel --> Trouser is the correct output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the data is it stands, you cannot get the results you are after. To be able to achieve this, you need to be able to order your data, using an `ORDER BY` clause, and ordering on either of these column does not achieve the same result as the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (Product varchar(20),HeaderFlag char(1));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('Furniture','Y'),
      ('Bed','N'),
      ('Table','N'),
      ('Chair','N'),
      ('Cosmetics','Y'),
      ('Lipbalm','N'),
      ('Lipstick','N'),
      ('Eyeliner','N'),
      ('Apparel','Y'),
      ('Shirt','N'),
      ('Trouser','N');
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY Product;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY HeaderFlag
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

AS you can see, the orders both differ.

If you add a column you can order on though (I'm going to use an `IDENTITY`) then you can achieve this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (I int IDENTITY, Product varchar(20),HeaderFlag char(1));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('Furniture','Y'),
      ('Bed','N'),
      ('Table','N'),
      ('Chair','N'),
      ('Cosmetics','Y'),
      ('Lipbalm','N'),
      ('Lipstick','N'),
      ('Eyeliner','N'),
      ('Apparel','Y'),
      ('Shirt','N'),
      ('Trouser','N');
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
ORDER BY I;
```

Then you can use a cumulative `COUNT` to put the values into groups and get the header:

```sql
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT YT.I,
           YT.Product,
           YT.HeaderFlag,
           COUNT(CASE YT.HeaderFlag WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY I ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT),
Split AS(
    SELECT G.I,
           MAX(CASE G.HeaderFlag WHEN 'Y' THEN Product END) OVER (PARTITION BY G.Grp) AS Category,
           G.Product,
           G.HeaderFlag
    FROM Grps G)
SELECT S.Category,
       S.Product
FROM Split S
WHERE HeaderFlag = 'N'
ORDER BY S.I;
```

Comment: That's great @Larnu! I'll insert an `IDENTITY` column in the input dataset

Comment: My 2 cents, if this is a 1 time only operation then IDENTITY column makes sense.  It was +1 from me for this excellent answer.  If the table is going to be deleted/inserted and maintained then IDENTITY might not be the way to go.

Comment: Ideally, the OP should not be storing the data in the format they are, @SteveC . I'm *hoping* the reason they are asking the question is so that they can fix their design.

Comment: @Steve this is a one-off operation. And you both are right, I wouldn't ideally store the data in this format, but just requires to be done this way for this ad-hoc task. thanks both!